# Exception at the time of GWT compile

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

When I Build the project with GWT Compiler then I found exception on console:

MyConsole:

```
Compiling module com.ems.EMSWeb
   Compiling 5 permutations
      Compiling permutation 0...
      Compiling permutation 1...
      Compiling permutation 2...
      Compiling permutation 3...
      Compiling permutation 4...
   Compile of permutations succeeded
Linking into D:\Workspace3\EMSWeb\war\emsweb
   Linking public artifacts into D:\Workspace3\EMSWeb\war
      Emitting resource 0A9476898799A150D840F0B1C3672921.cache.png
         [ERROR] Fatal error emitting this artifact
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace3\EMSWeb\war\emsweb\0A9476898799A150D840F0B1C3672921.cache.png (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.OutputFileSetOnDirectory$1.<init>(OutputFileSetOnDirectory.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.OutputFileSetOnDirectory.createNewOutputStream(OutputFileSetOnDirectory.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.OutputFileSet.openForWrite(OutputFileSet.java:57)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.StandardLinkerContext.produceOutput(StandardLinkerContext.java:496)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.doProduceOutput(Link.java:393)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.link(Link.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:235)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:149)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:156)
   Link succeeded
   Compilation succeeded -- 96.563s
```

Please give me suggestion, why this exception i am facing.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably some application using this file while you trying to write into.
Check if there any application reads this file or maybe you don't have administrative rights?

Or try to delete these cache files if nothing helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. you may be right but after restarting the system problem is resolved.